# Cocoa app won't launch on OS X 10.6

Tags: xcode, cocoa

A user with a Mac Pro running Snow Leopard gets this when he attempts to run my app, developed on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.5 using XCode 7.0.1.

[image]

The OS X deployment option is set to 10.6 for the project and the .xibs *Builds for option* is set to OS X 10.6 and later.
 What have I missed?

Comment: What language is the app written in?

Comment: You may have set a different deployment target for the app target within your project. That is, projects and targets can each independently specify a deployment target, and the target's setting overrides the project's. Another possible reason could be if you're using a storyboard for your main interface. Storyboards require 10.10 or later.

Comment: @Ken The deployment target is also set to 10.6 under Build Settings/Deployment. No storyboard.

Comment: Cocoa is not a language, it is a set of APIs. Objective-C, Swift, C++, etc are languages.

Comment: @zaph - Does Cocoa apply to any language other than Obj-c or c++? Why do you want to know the language?

Comment: Cocoa interoperates with other languages such as Swift and several 3rd party development projects use other languages. Cocoa refers to the APIs for OS X, CocoaTouch for iOS. If the language is Swift there are deployment limitations. So, more spicifically is the language Swift?

Comment: @Ken - The problem turned out to be the target's OS X Deployment setting. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Zaph - OK, thanks for the info. The language is Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had set the deployment target for the project, but the target has a separate setting which overrides the project's. You had to either remove that target setting (so the project's was in control) or set it to 10.6, too.